# Clearing UIWebView Cache on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a Phonegap App where I need at some point to remove the html cache because I have updated the images in my app.

I have tried this :

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```

Called in a plugin via javascript, the i do :

```
location.reload( true )
```

But I still see the same image that seems to be cached.

Is there another way of doing this ? I can tell the user to quit the app and kill it and relaunch it after.

Thanks !!

Comment: can you Please tell us which version of CORDOVA you are using?
We are having issue that UIWEBVIEW clears the Caches as soon as application exits. So when I run the application Next Time With WIFI off. No image appears. 
[Please see our query Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446317/ios-phonegap-application-ignoring-cache-headers-and-not-caching-images)

Comment: I think it's the ios behavior to clean the memory once the app is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to completely remove the cache directory in your app for example at the very first start of the app

Answer (score 0):

You Can have URL versioning system for images. As I have mentioned here.

http://www.abksharma.in/2013/10/caching-using-javascript-versioning.html

request images with below URL param.

```
http://s.wordpress.org/screenshots/3.5/ss5-dfw.gif?1
http://web-sniffer.net/
Above is truly cached image with below headers
```

For DATA we can Use below.

[How to Enable ajax request caching for semi dynamic data (ie JSON)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269878/how-to-enable-ajax-request-caching-for-semi-dynamic-data-ie-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this by add timestamp after the url.Then you can make sure that the url you request everytime is different.

Just like this:http://www.demo.com/xxxx?t=`timestamp`.

The javascript code just like this:

```
var url = 'xxxx/xxx?timestamp=' + Date.now();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these helped me.

I was afraid I was going to have to resort to generating unique file names and cleaning up when done.

This worked great.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABkAAAAZCAYAAADE6YVjAeu
... snip data ....
YII=">
```

[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)